# Call GraphQL api from Rest endpoint in spring boot returning null value

Tags: spring-boot, rest, graphql

From my rest endpoint I am trying to call 3rd party graphql api but in response I am getting null values.

**Request:**

```
{
  "query": "query($id: String!) { hiringOrganization (id: $id) { name } }",
  "variables": {
    "id": "seekAnzPublicTest:organization:seek:93WyyF1h"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "data": {
    "hiringOrganization": {
      "name": "Acme Corp"
    }
  }
}
```

Inside the resource folder I have placed Query and variable request:

```
query($id: String!) { hiringOrganization (id: $id) { name } }
```

Variables:

```
{
  "id": "hiringId"
}
```

From Postman I am getting the below response:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Calling the Query and variables from resource folder:

```
public static String getSchemaFromFileName(final String fileName) throws IOException {
        if(fileName.contains("Variables")){
            log.info("inside variables::"+fileName);
            return new String(
                    GraphqlSchemaReaderUtil.class.getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream("seekGraphQL/variables/"+fileName+".graphql")
                            .readAllBytes()
            );
        } else {
            log.info("inside query::"+fileName);
            return new String(
                    GraphqlSchemaReaderUtil.class.getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream("seekGraphQL/query/" + fileName + ".graphql")
                            .readAllBytes()
            );
        }
    }
```

**Calling the graphql endpoint:**

```
public Mono<HiringDTO> getHirerDetails(final String id) throws IOException {

        GraphqlRequestBody requestBody=new GraphqlRequestBody();
        final String query= GraphqlSchemaReaderUtil.getSchemaFromFileName("hiringQuery");
        final String variables= GraphqlSchemaReaderUtil.getSchemaFromFileName("hiringVariables");
        log.info("before id::"+id);
        requestBody.setQuery(query);
        requestBody.setVariables(variables.replace("hiringId",id));
        log.info("id::"+id);
        return webclient.post()
                .uri(url)
                .bodyValue(requestBody)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(HiringDTO.class);
    }
```

My rest end point is a post request which has hiring Id in request body . I don't know why I am getting the null values. Please assist me to find out the issues.

Postman request/response:
[image]